# Plone 3 / outgoing email over SSL

Tags: smtp, plone

We are configuring email out for old Plone site. Do Plone 3 support SMTP with SSL? The situation is little unclear whether this is 1) possible out of box 2) possible with (some) add-on 3) not possible

In this case Plone would directly negotiate with SMTP server (like Google's) instead of using any local MTA on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL support came with Python 2.6.

You can hack in the support to Python 2.4 through backporting Python 2.6 by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Plone 3 uses SecureMailHost, which supports TLS.  Plone can use remote SMTP servers.

Comment: Any instructions how to configure it, because it is not entirely clear from Mail setting screens and we cannot get it work.

Comment: I believe (based on reading the minimal docs), that it tries to use TLS by default. For a remote server, you should be able to just put in the remote server address.  I'm no expert on this, but if you're experiencing problems, perhaps you can share more details and others can jump in.

Comment: On it. Looks like problem might be actually deeper in Python smtplib and might require some special options to just make it work.